# How do I return the difference from two DateTimeFields in Django Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a simple timesheet that includes time in, time out, and total time in separate columns, but I'm running into troubles trying to work with the DateTimeFields. I initially tried this in my models.py:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  time_in = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  total_time = models.Duration(time_out - time_in)
```

and after reading some answers I tried this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
  time_in = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  time_out = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  @property
  def duration(self):
    return self.time_out - self.time_in
```

and both returned TypeErrors (- is an unsupported operand for DateTimeField). I tried adding this to the View:

```
def new_entry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            timeIn = form.cleaned_data.get('time_in')
            timeOut = form.cleaned_data.get('time_out')
            totalTime = timeOut - timeIn
            form.save()
```

But if this is the right direction to take, I'm not sure how to send it back to the model and into my database table without it being a circular import.

Comment: what version of django are you using? your second try should be working.

Comment: The second version, with `@property`, looks right to me - at least for model instances!. If you're getting an error about subtracting `DateTimeField` that looks to me like it's being evaluated on the class rather than an instance - maybe review your admin definitions to make sure you're not trying to declare `duration` as an editable field anywhere there?

Comment: As mentioned by the others your second solution should work. For your view: You do not need to handle the form fields. It is ok just if you just do: if form.is_valid():             form.save()

Comment: I tried again and the second option no longer returns TypeErrors (not sure what I fixed, but ok!) However, I've been reading about the property object it returns, and I can't figure out how to turn that object into a field I can save to the database as it saves time_in and time_out.

Comment: If you're saving time_in and time_out, you don't need to save a distinct duration field. The point of turning a derived value like duration into a property is to avoid storing redundant information. Especially because calculating the difference whenever you need it is more reliable than storing it two ways and hoping you don't get it out of sync.

Comment: Got it. I'll just avoid adding it in the first place and calculate it with queries. Thanks!